# How can I specify the columns returned by DESCRIBE TABLE?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know I can do `describe table a_table` to describe the columns in a table in Snowflake. However, I'd like to limit the columns that are returned to, say, `name` and `comment` to create a codebook of that table with only this information. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe execute a query like `SELECT name, comment FROM a_table` and afterwards, run `DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID()` in the same session?

Comment: The thing is that `name` and `comment` are columns in the description of `a_table`, not the table itself. I've been trying stuff with `last_query_id()`, but this feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`information_schema`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns) instead of doing describe

```
select column_name, comment from information_schema.columns
where concat_ws('.'table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) = "db.schema.tablename"
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan) will give you what you need.

```sql
DESCRIBE TABLE a_table;
SELECT "name", "comment"
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

While the option of retrieving from Information Schema will also work for this request, there are other queries that do not have equivalent Information Schema views available.